# Staining veneer in humid weather

Tags: finishing, staining, polyurethane

I am working in my garage in Wisconsin in August so needless to say it’s super muggy/humid.  I’ve veneered my speaker cabinet and I’m getting ready to stain.  Should I bring in the cabinets and put them down my dehumidifier for a while before I bring them back up to stain?
I’m going to use wipe-on satin poly for my finish after staining.  Should I just aplomb that inside by the dehumidifier or would it be okay to take the cabinets in, have them sit in a dehumidifed area and then take them out for the poly coats? 
What is the overall impact of high humidity on this process?

Comment: You can bring wood into the house prior to completing a project, to get it acclimated to the normal indoor conditions. But you shouldn't try to speed this process up, that's a recipe for warping and/or other issues. Acclimation should be expected to take a couple of weeks if the conditions are quite different, at minimum a few days.

Comment: Re. your "super muggy/humid" conditions, you need to give some details. For some 45% is really humid, for others it's closer to 100%! And how different this is from the static or average conditions inside the house are a big factor. *Huge* difference between a house where open windows and fans are largely used to make the inside comfortable versus one with central air, or a number of window-mounted air conditioners running periodically through the day.

Comment: It’s between 70 and 100%.  Could I still do the staining outside without the acclimation method?  Would it just take longer?  Then I could have it acclimate inside before putting the finish on.

Comment: Also, Minwax suggests this “pretreatment” would I need that with newer veneer?  I’m hesitant to use it because if it doesn’t dry then it will make things look weird

Comment: People working in humid parts of the US (and elsewhere in the world, like much of the tropics, parts of Australia etc.) often have to do their finishing when RH is above 70%. In some parts of the UK it's rarely below 70-75 and regularly tops 90. Whether you'll have problems is something you should test for though, this being a classic case for doing preliminary testing — you *never* stain the final project without testing first, even if you've used the stain before. But it goes double when you're using a new stain (even a new container of stain you've used previously because batches can vary).

Comment: Ive been testing on scrap veneer.  Should by scrap be affixed to something to get an exact replica?  Also, with water based stain, I’ll have to do each sides of my box individually, correct?  I should test how long I leave it on too, correct?  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Yes, you won't get the same effects on loose veneer as you would on the same thing stuck down on to your substrate. As a general rule all finishing tests should be done on stock prepped *exactly* the same as on the project, e.g. same amount of sanding, up to the same final grit. Re. waterbased stains, yes I think you'll want to do one face at a time being careful about stain sloshing on to the next and previous faces.